# Finding the unique elements in a list without losing element names

Tags: r, unique

```
l <- as.list(c(1, 1, 2))
names(l) <- c("a", "b", "c")
unique(l)
```

I would like to find the unique elements in a list without losing the names of the elements in the list. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Use `duplicated` instead. `l[!duplicated(l)]`

Comment: That was easy - Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bit of conceptual problem, here the unique elements of `l` are 1 and 2.  However, 1 belongs to both `"a"` and `"b"`, so which name would you want returned for 1? If only the first instance of 1 and the associated name, I would use `!duplicated` instead of `unique` as this returns logicals you can use to index `l` and keep the names

```
l[!duplicated(l)]
```